# Extending an HDMI port or Display cable?

Tags: hdmi

I am working on building this project for my Raspberry Pi well I need to extend the HDMI port of this monitor http://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/hp-22er-215-inch-display

I need to place the display in an enclosure, so the horizontal HDMI connector with a regular cable would cause the case to be too deep. So I need to basically relocate the port onto a breadboard and then connect to my raspberry pi. Any ideas? I was considering desoldering it and attempting to get wires to lineup and connect to it. Or somehow extending the ribbon cable coming from the board to the monitor so that I could put it in a separate box or something.

Any suggestions on if it would be a better option to extend the HDMI port or somehow extend the display ribbon cable?

Comment: good luck with that. Display links have bit rates significantly above 1 Gb/s, ie. very high-frequency signals. You can't just "breadboard" those.

Comment: Well I'm open to suggestions on somehow extending it from the monitor into a base station of some sort to keep the form factor small.

Comment: Would a laptop monitor work better possibly?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a regular cable?

Comment: What @Passerby said. "I don't want to" is not an engineering reason, especially if "the thing I don't want to do is what everyone does, and that's probably for a reason". So, please *explain* why you *cannot* use a proper display cable.

Comment: As I stated our port is vertical so it adds an additional depth to my case. And the case has to be a slim form factor has it is the same size as a mirror. The goal is to make it as thin as possible, I'd love to use the monitor and just find a horizontal HDMI and power port but I haven't had much luck without spending excess of $200 for a monitor.

Comment: We can't have a 3 inch deep frame just to fit an HDMI port. It makes the mirror seem very cheap, and less like a mirror.

Comment: Think of it has a kiosk almost where the frame can be thin, and electronics relocated to the base of the station.

Comment: You didn't state that, that's why we asked.

Comment: Cabling solutions for consumer electronics are not on topic here; buy the right angle connector for the monitor and mount the pi parallel to the screen glass.  Or simply use a touchscreen computer - something tablet derived with a proper on-board flash it likely to be far more reliable in service than the pi's reliance on an SD card.

Comment: It is 100% on topic. OP Is asking how to modify a connector `modifying their electronics for other use` in order to make their own product or project. It's a design issue.

Comment: No, it isn't.  First, that's not practical.  Second, it fails the understanding the details of the circuitry involved criteria for the topicalness of modifying-existing-products questions.

Comment: You purposely twist in a way that means "if you have to ask, then it's off topic". That would make every single question on this site off topic.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, thank you Passerby for your suggestions. I am going back to the drawing board. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the issue is a horizontal port which would cause issues fitting in a case, there are only a few solutions.

1. Replace the connector with a right angle one with the same foot print. Highly unlikely.
2. Extend the connector with some wire. This may leave it fragile. Delicate soldering skills required. Be prepared for solder bridges. May result in errors and lower bandwidth.
3. Solder a cut cable directly to it, removing the connector completely. May be fragile, May also result in errors and lower bandwidth. Same soldering issues as 2.
4. If the video input board is separate from the display controller board, extend that cable instead.
5. Simplest solution, ***use a right angle adapter or cable with a right angle connector.*** This is a plug and play solution, and may only add 0.5 to 1 inch, not 3 inches. If you need more, then you can crack the plastic open. Or use a FPC version like https://www.ebay.com/i/262114109807 can't vouch for the quality but it has no depth beyond the connector and pcb.

Alternatively, use a display directly from the RPi's LVDS interface, bypassing HDMI.

You mention a display cable, likely the flat FPC that goes to the display internally. That is even harder to modify properly.

Comment: +1 Thank you so much for answering this. I do believe the right angle cable is the easiest solution, and I understand the bandwidth issues. I was extremely worried about the soldering for this, way too difficult.